# Exchange 2010 - E-mail Address Policies - users missing but they exists in AD!

Tags: active-directory, exchange

So I have a bunch of users created in the Active Directory.
I want to make them into email enabled users.  From following online directions and "Email Address Policy" is the way to do it.

However, when I create the policy, container as root, "all recipient types" then in Preview only mail-enabled users are shown and not regular Active Directory users.

How can I make all my AD users as email-enabled users??

Answer (score 3):

Your nomenclature "mail enabled" is a bit fuzzy. I suspect you want to create mailboxes for all of these user accounts. (I suspect the doc you're referring to is [this one](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232171(EXCHG.149).aspx) and it, too, uses the fuzzy "mail-enabled user" nomenclature. In Exchange 2003 "mail-enabled" versus "mailbox-enabled" [meant different things](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998069(EXCHG.65).aspx). The nomenclature changed in the administration interface in Exchange 2007 but, obviously, some writers are Microsoft are still using the old nomenclature.)

Here's an easy way to create mailboxes for users in the Exchange Management Console (EMC). You can do the same thing from PowerShell, too, but I suspect you'll find the GUI a bit more comfortable.

- From EMC, expand the "Microsoft Exchange On-Premises" node and the "Recipient Configuration" node. Right-click the "Mailbox" node and choose "New Mailbox...".
- In the "New Mailbox" dialog leave the default selection "User Mailbox" selected and click "Next".
- Change the "Create mailboxes for:" radio button to "Existing Users" and click "Add".
- Select the user accounts you want to create mailboxes for in the list and click "OK". Click "Next" to proceed.
- Unless you know of any reason to change the defaults on the "Mailbox Settings" page leave the defaults intact and click "Next".
- Finally click "New" to create the mailboxes for the users.

Answer (score 0):

Check under your Exchange Management Console. Go to Organization Configuration > Hub Transport > Email Address Policies. Choose the email Address Policy you had just setup. Check to see if it is configured as you it should be.

[MSExchange.org](http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/managing-email-address-policies.html) has a good walk through.